# How to compile chromium with debugging flag?

Tags: c++, chromium

I am running a custom version of chromium and would like to debug it.
When compiling C++ code with `gcc` the `-g` option allows debugging.
Though, chromium is compiled with ninja.

The debugging flag of ninja is for ninja execution and not for the compiled chromium.
Do you have any idea how I can compile chromium with the debugging flag for chromium ?

Thanks !

Clems4ever

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/NinjaBuild#Build_instructions

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Guess I didn't searched enough. Thanks !